# How to get records created in last 30 mins in a single SOQL query

Tags: java, salesforce, soql

I'm bit new to SFDC development. I'm currently working on project for which I need to get records created in last 30 mins from a SObject.
Note: I want do this in a single soql query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
DateTime timeNow = System.now(); // Get the time now
DateTime X30MinutesAgo = timeNow.addMinutes(-30); // Subtract 30 minutes from it
System.DEBUG([SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE createdDate <:timeNow AND createdDate >:X30MinutesAgo]);// This will return all accounts created in the last 30 minutes
```